# Repair torn insulation facing paper with tape?

Tags: insulation

Two problems with the image below. The paper is torn in spots. Can I just tape over that with shipping tape? Or what else?

Also, the paper doesn't reach the stud on the right side. Can I use tape there again? Should I staple the tape to the stud?

I know some will say to replace it but it's just the one spot and I don't want to buy a roll of insulation just for this.

[image]

Comment: To tell the truth I would not worry about the tear if anything masking tape as cellophane tape will bleed out and fall off but masking the 2 paper surfaces bond better. If an undersized bay was cut down staple the good side it will stay in place.

Comment: @EdBeal I said "mask" but I meant "face". I was going to put shipping tape over the facing that was torn.